# Silverstripe 3.0- script tags getting stripped from editor content after save and publish

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tinymce, silverstripe

I need to extend the allowed tags in SilverStripe 3.0  editor (Tinymce) and also allow javascript in it

I added the below code in mysite/_config.php:

HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms')->setOptions(array('valid_elements' => "* [*]"));

above code works and tags like form and input are accepted....

But its not accepting javascript..(i have tried alert('hello');) 
It remains after clicking update on the editor, but  gets stripped after clicking 'save and publish'

same code in version 2.4.7 accepted script but it was commented out and CDATA was added..

please tell me how i can allow javascript  in the editor.....

Comment: Never had any luck with JS in SS's TinyMCE editor. Same deal with IFrames unfortunately. You may want to create a separate field to add JS to the page. Or, you can create a Shortcode that renders JS based on a predefined template. SSBits [has a tutorial](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/2-4-using-short-codes-to-embed-a-youtube-video/) for SS 2.x that you should be able to adapt, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Benjamin.....I am also considering replacing TinyMCE, an option...I can do the replacing part but can you or anyone else tell me how I can create a new field type that has some other editor..any references or links would be helpful.....

Comment: I don't think anyone ever replaced TinyMCE in SS 2.x because of the tight coupling with the CMS interface (namely adding images and links). I remember a while back that decoupling the WYSIWYG editor from the CMS was on the roadmap for 3.0, but I have no idea what the status is with that now. Please post here if you find a solution :)

Comment: Hey Neelam, in case you're still wondering, I replaced TinyMCE with a Markdown Editor here, you could use it as reference: https://github.com/wolfv/silverstripe-markdowneditorfield

Comment: There is an official tip for that, which can be found http://www.silverstripe.org/blog/quick-tips-allowing-extra-tags-and-attributes-in-the-rich-text-editor/

Answer (score 1):

This was reported and resolved, however isn't slated to be released until 3.3: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/3611

For a short-term workaround you could try: https://github.com/kinglozzer/htmleditorscripts